# nicely working in chrome but not in IE(internet explorer)

Tags: php, laravel-5, vuejs2

I am new in Vuejs. i have a chat system in vuejs and laravel. when my message is too big it is not working correctly in IE. first it is sending half of the message and then full message. that means for every enter it is sending two message.
but code is working well in chrome.

```
  <textarea v-model="Keijiban" @keydown.enter="send" @click="selectContact(kokyaku1)" placeholder="ここにメッセージを入力してください。"></textarea>



methods: { 
            send(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                 //alert(this.Keijiban);
                if (this.Keijiban == '') {
                    return;
                }

                this.$emit('send', this.Keijiban);
                this.Keijiban = '';
            },
```

then message is sent to another component. here is the code from another component

```
 <MessageComposer :kokyaku1="kokyaku1" @readkorsi="middleman" @send="sendMessage"/>

methods: {
            sendMessage(text) {

                if (!this.kokyaku1) {
                    return;
                }

                axios.post('conversation/send', {
                    contact_id: this.kokyaku1.bango,
                    text: text

                }).then((response) => {
                    this.$emit('new', response.data);
                })
            },
```

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: version is 11.765

Comment: I faced the similar issue today after the last windows update. It was fine before the update

Comment: what's your solution.?? is it a problem of code or Internet explorer??